# Verb of "a factory"

Tags: verbs

Speaking of programing design patterns, there is "a factory".
What would be the correct verb?

To factorize / factorise is the mathmatical term not related to "a factory".

To factor [in ...] is a form of "a fact" not related to factory either.

I know "to manufacture" as an alternative, but what word is closer to factory?

Comment: Synonyms for [manufacture](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/manufacture): 

    assemble
    complete
    construct
    create
    fabricate
    mass-produce
    synthesize
    accomplish

    carve
    cast
    cobble
    compose
    execute
    fashion
    forge
    form

    frame
    machine
    make
    mill
    mold
    prefab
    process
    shape

    tool
    fudge together
    make up
    put together
    throw together
    turn out

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A programmer answer rather than English usage -- the verb is construct, since a factory makes objects, and that involves calling a constructor function.

> `AbstractConnectionFactory` will construct an concrete instance of `IDbConnection`.

Answer (score 7):

Factory comes from [Manufactory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manufactory) - the verb is Manufacture.

```
man·u·fac·to·ry  (măn′yə-făk′tə-rē)
n. pl. man·u·fac·to·ries
A factory or manufacturing plant.
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest verb is "to fabricate".

Relate to the german words "Fabrik" -> "fabrizieren".

Derived from the Latin "făbrĭcāre", to build, create

Answer (score 1):

Keep it short and simple, especially in programming names. A good verb for what a factory does is:

> **Make**

Answer (score 1):

mold, cast, machine, frame, outline, assembly-line, process, execute, efficiency, having things down to a "science" or a "recipe." These are what I came up with after inputting manufacture using thesaurus.com and using some of my own ideas.